# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar la referencia del padre de un elemento con posición absoluta?

Tags: javascript, css, posicionamiento

Tengo un contenedor div con **position: relative** y dentro tengo otros dos div con **position: absolute** que se posiciona en la esquina inferior izquierda y esquina inferior derecha.

```
<div class="padre">
  <div class="hijo hijo1"></div>
  <div class="hijo hijo2"></div>
</div>
```

```
.padre{
   position: relative;
   width: 300px;
   height: 100px;
   background-color: #242526;
}

.hijo{
   position: absolute;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
}

.hijo.hijo1{
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background-color: blue;
}

.hijo.hijo2{
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background-color: red;
}
```

Me gustaría cambiar la referencia del elemento hijo1 a **body**, pero sin afectar el posicionamiento del hijo2.

Cambiar el **position: relative** por **static** al padre no funciona, puesto que me rompe el posicionamiento del **hijo2**

¿Puedo hacerlo con jquery, o tengo que usar otra librería?

Comment: ¿Probaste si `position: fixed;` resuelve tu problema? Checa estas [soluciones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867244/force-position-absolute-to-be-relative-to-the-document-and-not-the-parent-con) a ver si alguna te sirve. Hay unas cuantas que usan JQuery.

Comment: No conocía esa propiedad, acabo de usarla y parece funcionar, Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

La posición `absolute` siempre hace referencia al contenedor padre posicionado más cercano. Como menciona Jaime Menéndez en su comentario, para que haga referencia al body, siempre puede utilizar `position: fixed`.

Comment: Lo intenté hace un momento y parece funcionar. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Ya resolví mi problema, gracias a las respuestas.
Para cambiar la posición de hijo utilizo jquery.
Con jquery hago algo como esto:

```
$(".hijo.hijo2").click(function(){
  $(".hijo2").css({
     "position" : "fixed",
     "top" : "50%",
     "left" : "50%",
     "transform" : "translate(-50%,-50%)"
   });
});
```

Esto me centra el contenido referente a la ventana, espero y a alguien más le sirva.
Ahora si se quiere cambiar la referencia a otro contenedor, también pude hacerlo de esta manera:

```
$(".hijo.hijo2").click(function(){
  $(".hijo2").appendTo("#otroPadre");
});
```

Sin embargo esto no es muy vistoso a la hora de hacer una animación o algo por el estilo, me tocó hacer un efecto **transform: scale** y asignarle una animación para que al pasarlo de un contenedor a otro, este se muestre mucho más suave, pero igual el salto al otro contenedor suele ser muy brusco.